# How to apply for loop in bash terminal

Tags: bash

I am new to bash and would like to get help how to run for loop.

Here is my question, I have 10 different sorted bam files(*.sorted.bam) and I would like to do indexing for each sorted bam files.

I know how to run it for single file using the command below

```
samtools index sample.sorted.bam
```

I would be happy if some one could show me how to run for multiple files

Best,
Amare

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the for..in loop like this:

```sh
for file in *.sorted.bam
do
  samtools index "$file"
done
```

or in a single line:

```sh
for file in *.sorted.bam; do samtools index "$file"; done
```

You can find more information on bash looping constructs here: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Looping-Constructs

Comment: Iterating over the output of `ls` is not quite desirable: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs#Enumerating_files_or_doing_stuff_with_files In this particular case using the glob pattern directly is better.

Comment: @IonuțG.Stan Edited the answer.